# Android : The JavaScript function is abnormal in my webview

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

Basically, I am developing a simple web viewer apps for my website.

And I did contain the essential codes in the **AndroidManifest.xml** and the **MainActivity.java**

This below is the **MainActivity.java**

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //hide the title bar
        // this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        WebView vistaWeb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        vistaWeb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        vistaWeb.clearCache(true);
        vistaWeb.clearHistory();
        vistaWeb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        vistaWeb.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);


        vistaWeb.loadUrl("http://mysite/login");
```

And It doesn't look like I missing anything in it but some Javascript functions are just not running when I access it with the app. But It works perfectly fine when I ran it on my browsers both in desktop and the phone.

[image]

P.s: I Consider I'm missing something in the Andriod code or please let me know if that's nothing wrong with it then I will double check my Javascript codes.

Comment: Is there any error in Chrome Developer Tool console ?

Comment: Not at all , sir.